# Scaling a canvas image in GWT

Tags: gwt, html5-canvas

I am having difficulties scaling the size of an image on an HTML canvas in GWT.  I can successfully render an image using this:

```
ImageData id = context.createImageData(width, height);
-- do some image manipulation here...   
context.putImageData(id, 0, 0);
```

That works great.  But then I'd like to scale the size of the image, so I add this to the very next line:

```
context.scale(scale, scale);
```

But nothing happens to the image, it does not scale.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how to scale an image:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwt_hmtl5#Image_Scale_/_Resize

Comment: Are you able to summarize that into the few essential pieces?